# how to check internet connectivity in node.js, electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to detect internet connectivity in node.js and electron.

my code notifies internet connectivity every 1 second.

but what I want is showing connectivity when it's connected, disconnected 
 **(only when connection is switched )** not every 1 second.

can I do that in node.js and electron?

**main.js**

```
const dns = require('dns');

function liveCheck() {
    dns.resolve('www.google.com', function(err, addr){
        if (err) {
            notifier.notify(
                {
                    appName: "com.myapp.id",
                    title: "network error",
                    message: "disconnected",
                    icon:"./facebook.png"
                }
            );
        }


 else{
            console.log("connected");
        }
    });
}

setInterval(function() {
    liveCheck()
     },1000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to keep the same logic, you need to add a flag to see if you switched from no connection to connected. I did that with the `isConnected`
flag:

```
const dns = require("dns");
let isConnected = false;

function liveCheck() {
  dns.resolve("www.google.com", function(err, addr) {
    if (err) {
      if (isConnected) {
        notifier.notify({
          appName: "com.myapp.id",
          title: "network error",
          message: "disconnected",
          icon: "./facebook.png",
        });
      }
      isConnected = false;
    } else {
      if (isConnected) {
        //connection is still up and running, do nothing
      } else {
        notifier.notify({
          appName: "com.myapp.id",
          title: "connection gained",
          message: "connected",
          icon: "./facebook.png",
        });
      }
      isConnected = true;
    }
  });
}

setInterval(function() {
  liveCheck();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: your code shows log every 1 second..  I want when it's connected, disconnected to notify not every 1 second

Comment: thanks! it works fine when it's online, it shows "connected" one time, but when it disconnected it shows notifications every 1second..

Comment: Hi! I just have a question! what if I change value of (isConnected) right after  notifier.notify({})?  Is there a reason changing the valuse after if..else statements close? I tried that and work same!

Comment: It's no problem, as long as it is done in the right scope

Answer (score 5):

navigator.onLine is not reliable method. So i found npm util to handle this situation

Install it `npm i check-internet-connected`

And use it

```
const checkInternetConnected = require('check-internet-connected');

  const config = {
    timeout: 5000, //timeout connecting to each try (default 5000)
    retries: 3,//number of retries to do before failing (default 5)
    domain: 'apple.com'//the domain to check DNS record of
  }

  checkInternetConnected(config)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Connection available");          
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("No connection", err);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me in the latest Electron version 4.0.8 on macOS, from a renderer process, using only Web API:

```
function notifyUser (event)
{
    let myNotification = new Notification
    (
        "com.myapp.id",
        { body: (event.type === 'online') ? "Internet available" : "No internet" }
    ); 
}
window.addEventListener ('online', notifyUser, false);
window.addEventListener ('offline', notifyUser, false);
```

References:

- [navigator.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine)
- [Online and offline events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events)
- [Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification)

Comment: online&offline is not trustable

Comment: @Kylin.Zhang why not?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur f.e when the windows is connected to VPN and you turn off Wifi/Ethernet the status wont change to offline. It seems that it checks the status of connection adapters which might not be the same thing as being connected to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

First, install `internet-available` package

```
npm install internet-available
```

And then,

```
var internetAvailable = require("internet-available");

// Set a timeout and a limit of attempts to check for connection
internetAvailable({
    timeout: 4000,
    retries: 10,
}).then(function(){
    console.log("Internet available");
}).catch(function(){
    console.log("No internet");
});
```

Comment: when I switch internet connection your code doesn't show log.. only first  when application executed it works

Comment: can you refer this link? https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/454/how-to-check-if-there-is-an-active-internet-connection-in-node-js