# Is is possible to make Desktop App with Nodejs along with Online connectivity

Tags: node.js, electron

I am trying build an application that can run offline and online too.  If the application is offline it must run with minimum functionality and if it get an internet it automatically push data online  Any references or tutorials would be appreciated.

any references that can help me to achieve this.

Comment: You wouldn't use NodeJS to build a desktop app, it's more suited to server-side use cases. You tagged this post with "electron" which would be a more likely Javascript-based framework. Perhaps you would like to rephrase the question along those lines?

Comment: @JasonNorwood-Young Incidentally, [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) uses NodeJS to provide a client-server relationship between a Node process and a modified Chromium "browser", with a specific set of APIs. So, the question is not that far off.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I concede that point. As an alternative to Electron, I also just spotted Gluon (https://gluonjs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, surely that's possible and you already mentioned the tools: node.js and electron are suitable. Most electron apps do that (whatsapp and joplin directly come to my mind).

You can look in the source of those already available apps, but it might be difficult. I would start with the tutorial of [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start) and search for the features as "check internet connectivity" (i.e. [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55096400/how-to-check-internet-connectivity-in-node-js-electron))

Your question is a bit to broadly stated to help in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, surely that's possible. you can use the node.js and electronJs with Angular are suitable.

For Angular and NodeJs refer the below document:
[Build a Basic CRUD App with Angular and Node](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/10/30/basic-crud-angular-and-node)

For ElectronJs refer the below demo project:

[Electron Samples](https://github.com/electron/simple-samples)

*Best luc*k !!